# Use mysqlite database converted from mysql in android app

Tags: android, mysql, database

For a schoolproject I have converted a php database from `MySQL` to `MySQLi` to use it in my android application.

I've looked into creating a android database using head's first book on android (2017) and according to that I need to manually create and insert every record in the database, but I already have all the data needed and one table even has 113 entries that need to be inserted.

Isn't there a way for me to import the existing database without completely creating it all over again?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) , hope it helps .

Comment: i have used sqlite browser to acces the file and read it's data but that is not what i am trying to achieve. I want this database (the one that is created) imported within the apk on install to the users device without having to manually creating bits of insertion code for every database entry

Comment: ok got it , did you tried to put your sql file into assets , and then read it ?

Comment: after some trying i got my database to transfer correctly, however since i scraped the data fom the overwatch website (all the heroes and their data), stored it in a php database in UTF-8 encoding, which for some reason messes with my characters, then i used a python script to convert mysql to mysqlite, i can open it fine in sqlite browser but when debugging the database has suddenly lost all of its tables.. when i open the .sqlite file in AS i get a couple of insert statements with A LOT of broken characters.. i am completely lost here

Answer (score 0):

Export SQL file from MySql and put it into assets folder. Read sql file from assets, use 'db.execSQL' method to create and insert all records of sql file. Some of the 'keywords' are working in SQLite of MySql so firstly remove these keywords from file.